# If $G$ is a finite group of order invertible on a scheme $X$, then does taking $G$-invariants send injectives to flasques?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be a finite group of order invertible on a scheme $X$. Let $I$ be an injective sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (or abelian groups) equipped with a $\mathcal{O}_X$-linear $G$-action.

Is $I^G$ also injective? Is it flasque? Is it acyclic for the global sections functor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I^G$ is a direct summand of $I$, and therefore injective.

The natural map $I^G\to I$ is split by the map $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g$.

Comment: Ah I didn't know direct summands of injectives are injective! Nice!